# Прибавить к рандому % от строения

Tags: php, случайные-числа

```
$_gold = rand(600,1000)/100 * $clan[obeliskk];
```

Делал вот так...
Где, выпадение голды рандомно от 600 до 1000.
К этому рандомному числу нужно прибавить %

Comment: `$_gold = rand(600,1000) * (100+$clan[obeliskk])/100;` так ?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос. Что к чему прибавить, что такое строение? В чем сам вопрос, если у вас уже есть решение?

Comment: splash58, спасибо! Все получилось!!!!

Comment: `obeliskk` если это не константа, то ключи указываются в кавычках